# Out and Ref parameters with FakeItEasy

Tags: c#, .net, tdd, mocking, fakeiteasy

I have a method that has an out parameter that returns a number of records. I would like to know how to mock it with FakeItEasy.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You should use the .AssignsOutAndRefParameters configuration method:

```
[Test]
public void Output_and_reference_parameters_can_be_configured()
{
    var fake = A.Fake<IDictionary<string, string>>();
    string ignored = null;

    A.CallTo(() => fake.TryGetValue("test", out ignored))
        .Returns(true)
        .AssignsOutAndRefParameters("foo");

    // This would of course be within you SUT.
    string outputValue = null;
    fake.TryGetValue("test", out outputValue);

    Assert.That(outputValue, Is.EqualTo("foo"));
}
```

Comment: @Patrik Hägne, If i have 2 out arguments in a function then how pass it to AssignsOutAndRefParameters() function.

Comment: @UmeshaMS, `.AssignsOutAndRefParameters("out1", "out2")

Comment: Link to the official documentation: https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/assigning-out-and-ref-parameters/